# Advanced AWK formatting

Tags: bash, awk

I am having problem using this awk command . It is not producing the result I want giving this input file. Can someone help me with this please?

I am searching for "Class:" value of "ABC".  When I find ABC . I like to assign the values associated with userName/servicelist/hostlist and port number to variables. ( please see output section )  to

```
   awk -v q="\"" '/ABC/{f=1;c++} 
   f && /userName|serviceList|hostList|portNumber/
                                 {sub(":",c"=",$1); 
                                 print $1 q $3 q
                                } 
                          /port:/{f=0;print ""}' filename
```

The file contains the following input

```
                      Instance: Ths is a test 
                           Class: ABC
Variables:
          udpRecvBufSize:          Numeric:          8190000
                userName:           String:test1
            pingInterval:          Numeric:                2
      blockedServiceList:           String:
       acceptAllServices:          Boolean:            False
             serviceList:           String:          ABC
                hostList:           String:    159.220.108.3
                protocol:           String:             JJJJ
             portNumber:          Numeric:            20001
                    port:           String:         RTR_LLLL
                             Children:


                          Instance: The First Server in the Loop 
                              Class: Servers
Variables:
                 pendout:          Numeric:                0
               overflows:          Counter:                0
         peakBufferUsage:          Numeric:              100
        bufferPercentage:            Gauge:                1 (0,100)
      currentBufferUsage:          Numeric:                1
         pendingBytesOut:          Numeric:                0
          pendingBytesIn:          Numeric:                1
           pingsReceived:          Counter:            13597
               pingsSent:          Counter:            87350
     clientToServerPings:          Boolean:             True
     serverToClientPings:          Boolean:             True
         numInputBuffers:          Numeric:               10
        maxOutputBuffers:          Numeric:              100
 guaranteedOutputBuffers:          Numeric:              100
      lastOutageDuration:           String:       0:00:00:00
      peakDisconnectTime:           String:
     totalDisconnectTime:           String:       0:00:00:00
          disconnectTime:           String:
       disconnectChannel:          Boolean:            False
      enableDacsPermTest:          Boolean:            False
          enableFirewall:          Boolean:            False
          dacsPermDenied:          Counter:                0
              dacsDomain:           String:
      compressPercentage:            Gauge:                0 (0,100)
     uncompBytesSentRate:            Gauge:                0    (0,9223372036854775807)





                           Instance: Ths is a test 
                               Class: ABC
Variables:
          udpRecvBufSize:          Numeric:          8190000
                userName:           String:test2
            pingInterval:          Numeric:                4
      blockedServiceList:           String:
       acceptAllServices:          Boolean:            False
             serviceList:           String:          DEF
                hostList:           String:    159.220.111.2
                protocol:           String:             ffff
              portNumber:          Numeric:            20004
                    port:           String:         JJJ_LLLL
                             Children:
```

This is the output I am looking for . Assigning variables

```
userName1="test1"
serviceList1="ABC"
hostList1="159.220.108.3"
portNumber1="2001"

userName2="test2"
serviceList2="DEF"
hostList2="159.220.111.2"
portNumber2="2004"
```

Comment: Sorry the CLASS input was  wrong i fixed  it. I use the variables to pass on to another part of my script to do additional stuff

Comment: This is purely an awk question -- there's no `bash` here at all; even the invocation line is pure POSIX sh (`sh` or `shell` if you wanted to tag for it), with no bashisms.

Comment: (Now, if you did want to know how to get the same output from your input using only native bash code and no awk, I'd be happy to help with that, but I don't read your question in such a way as to think that's something you're necessarily interested in).

Comment: ...and actually, if you were executing the generated code in a shell, you could write a more defensive / effectively secure version using bash builtins such as `printf '%q'` than you can in awk, which lacks such tools. (If an attacker can insert data into these variables, think what happens with an implementation that complies with your existing specification if one of the values contains `$()`).

Comment: In what language are the variable assignments? What escaping is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F: -v q="\"" '/Class: ABC/{f=1;c++;print ""}  \
     f && /userName|serviceList|hostList|portNumber/ \
         {gsub(/ /,"",$1);  \
          gsub(/ /,"",$3);  \
          print $1 c "=" q $3 q} \
        /Children:/{f=0}' vars

userName1="test1"
serviceList1="ABC"
hostList1="159.220.108.3"
portNumber1="20001"

userName2="test2"
serviceList2="DEF"
hostList2="159.220.111.2"
portNumber2="20004"
```

it will increment the counter for each "Class: ABC" pattern and set a flag. Will format and print the selected entries until the terminal pattern for the block.  This limits the context between the two patterns.

Comment: Thanks again karakfa !! The first two worked like a charm .. The format part not working for me  I piped the output of the second part into a file and passed it on to third section .. But it does not produce the results you have listed. I'll try again

Comment: I get something like this when I user the last format userName test1
userNametest1=""
             serviceList           ABC
serviceListABC=""
                hostList     159.220.108.3

Comment: radmin@s620728nj2sl04# awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: I am using the same input file as above

Comment: Also there should be          userName="test1"
serviceList="ABC"
hostList="159.220.108.3"
portNumber="20001"

Comment: also your formatting exclude th second part of the output.. The values are diffeernt - Please see the output section

Comment: userName1="test1"
serviceList1="ABC"
hostList1="159.220.108.3"
portNumber1="2001"

userName2="test2"
serviceList2="DEF"
hostList2="159.220.111.2"
portNumber2="2004"

Comment: example - Username is assigned the same value - So it does not produce the output that i look for . Stil not working _ I copied and paste the exact input file

Comment: Hi Thanks again - It does look much better now .. I tired ur latest and this s what I am seeing                                                  userNametest1=""
serviceListABC=""
hostList159.220.108.3=""
portNumber20001=""
userNametest2=""
serviceListDEF=""
hostList159.220.111.2=""
portNumber20004=""

Comment: Ok - This is the output of your second command I pipe into a file      userName test1
             serviceList           ABC
                hostList     159.220.108.3
             portNumber             20001
                userName test2
             serviceList           DEF
                hostList     159.220.111.2
              portNumber             20004

Comment: I copy and paste and I got this result

Comment: userName1="test2"
serviceList1="DEF"
hostList1="159.220.111.2"
portNumber1="20004"

Comment: 2 - I run ur second command against file1 and pipe that to  fiile2  then I put the format part of what you provided in a script and name it format. I run format script against file2  and the result I get is as follow ... userNametest1=""
serviceListABC=""
hostList159.220.108.3=""
portNumber20001=""
userNametest2=""
serviceListDEF=""
hostList159.220.111.2=""
portNumber20004=""

Comment: this is what I put in the format script                                                        awk -F: -v q="\"" '/Class: ABC/{c++} /userName|serviceList|hostList|portNumber/ \
         {gsub(/ /,"",$1);  \
          gsub(/ /,"",$3);  \
          print $1 c "=" q $3 q}' file2

Comment: Sorry. It's working ALMOST. I ran it against a larger file. I see that I have a portNumber line in another segment of the file under different Class: type. Script picking that 1 as well. To test I added another Class section under input file Class: test & added a portNumber line under it and when I ran d command it displayed that portnumber as well.  the search not working   c output below  userName1="test1"
serviceList1="ABC"
hostList1="159.220.108.3"
portNumber1="20001"
userName2="test2"
serviceList2="DEF"
hostList2="159.220.111.2"
portNumber2="20004"
portNumber2="20004"

Comment: @theuniverseisflat, you might try the current version of my answer there -- the first version followed the same pattern your original script did (waiting for the ABC class and setting a flag which never changed even if the class was edited further), but the current revision follows all class changes.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to assign to a series of variables, then rather than parsing the whole file at once, perhaps you could just extract the specific parts that you're interested in one by one. For example:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v record=1 -v var=userName 'NR == record { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (sub("^\\s*" var ".*:\\s*", "", $i)) print $i }' file
test1
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v record=1 -v var=serviceList 'NR == record { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (sub("^\\s*" var ".*:\\s*", "", $i)) print $i }' file
ABC
```

The awk script could be put inside a shell function and used like this:

```
parse_file() {
    record=$1
    var=$2
    file=$3

    awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v record="$record" -v var="$var" 'NR == record {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (sub("^\\s*" var ".*:\\s*", "", $i)) print $i 
    }' "$file"
}

userName1=$(parse_file 1 userName file)
serviceList1=$(parse_file 1 serviceList file)
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks .. for your reply and suggestion.  I have to parse through the file.. for this purpose. But I if I cannot get it to work I will use ur approach

Comment: Tom I tried ur commands as well - But not getting any output at all .. But thanks

Comment: Some versions of awk don't understand `\\s` - try changing them to `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash 4.0 or newer, there's no need for awk here at all:

```
flush() {
  if (( ${#hostvars[@]} )); then
    for varname in userName serviceList hostList portNumber; do
      [[ ${hostvars[$varname]} ]] && {
        printf '%q=%q\n' "$varname" "${hostvars[$varname]}"
      }
    done
    printf '\n'
  fi
  hostvars=( )
}

class=
declare -A hostvars=( )
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line = *"Class: "* ]] && class=${line#*"Class: "} 
  [[ $class = ABC ]] || continue
  case $line in
    *:*:*)
      IFS=$': \t' read varName varType value <<<"$line"
      hostvars[$varName]=$value
      ;;
    *"Variables:"*)
      flush
      ;;
  esac
done
flush
```

---

Notable points:

- The full set of defined variables are collected in the `hostvars` associative array (what other languages might call a "map" or "hash"), even though we're only printing the four names defined to be of interest. More interesting logic could thus be defined that combined multiple variables to decide what to output, &c.
- The `flush` function is defined outside the loop so it can be used in multiple places -- both when starting a new block (as detected, here, by seeing `Variables:`), and when at the end-of-file.
- The output varies from what you requested in that it includes quotes only if necessary -- but that quoting is guaranteed to be correct and sufficient for bash to parse without room for security holes even if the strings being emitted would otherwise contain security-relevant content. Think about correctly handling a case where `serviceList` contains `$(rm -rf /*)'$(rm -rf /*)'` (the duplication being present to escape single quotes); `printf %q` makes this easy, whereas awk has no equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
@(collect)
@(skip)Class: ABC
Variables:
@  (gather)
 userName: String:@user
 serviceList: String: @servicelist
 hostList: String: @hostlist
 portNumber: Numeric: @port
@  (until)
 Children:
@  (end)
@(end)
@(deffilter shell-esc
   ("\"" "\\\"") ("$" "\\$") ("`" "\\'")
   ("\\" "\\\\"))
@(output :filter shell-esc)
@  (repeat :counter i)
userName@(succ i)="@user"
serviceList@(succ i)="@servicelist"
hostList@(succ i)="@hostlist"
portNumber@(succ i)="@port"
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data
userName1="test1"
serviceList1="ABC"
hostList1="159.220.108.3"
portNumber1="20001"
userName2="test2"
serviceList2="DEF"
hostList2="159.220.111.2"
portNumber2="20004"
```

**Note 1:** Escaping is necessary if the data may contain characters which are special between quotes in the target language. The `shell-esc` filter is based on the assumption that the generated variable assignments are shell syntax. It can easily be replaced.

**Note 2:** The code assumes that each `Class: ABC` has all of the required variables present. It will not work right if some are missing, and there are two ways to address it by tweaking the `@(gather)` line:

- failure:

  ```
  @(gather :vars (user servicelist hostlist port))
  ```

  Meaning: fail if any of these four variables are not gathered. The consequence is that the entire `Class: ABC` section with missing variables is skipped.
- default missing:

  ```
  @(gather :vars (user (servicelist "ABC") hostlist port))
  ```

  Meaning: must gather the four variables `user`, `servicelist`, `hostlist` and `port`. However, if `serviceList` is missing, then it gets the default value `"ABC"` and is treated as if it had been found.